# good resource for android admob tutorial

Tags: android, admob

Is there anyone who has any good tutorial about admob for android apps? from registering , getting the API, placing ads in apps and paying out?
I've never dealt with admob before so I don't understand how to do it. I tried to register in admob, but looks like I need to register my apps in market before I'm able to place ads in my apps. is this really is the way?

Comment: The amount of accepted answers of your total questions. It is a measurement of how many times you have returned to your previous questions, either rewarding people who give answer or adding your own sollution if any possible

Comment: ah that's because I still have some question for the answer, and the answerer still not answering the question. that's why. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- You don't need your app in the market to use ads in your app(for example, testing your app).  Just follow the tutorial mentioned below and test your app out with ads before submitting.
- on admob's website, click "add site/app". fill in the details that are required.  for the market URL, enter in `market://details?id=your.package.name.goes.here`.
- these details can be changed anytime, so don't worry about it and change when you want..
- there is no "final" process for when your app is ready to submit.  if it works while testing, nothing more needs to be done before submitting your app.
- see http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html for examples/tutorials installing the ads in your application

Comment: I've never thought that the URL can be changed anytime. thank you :)

Comment: right.  you really don't need to be TOO careful when it comes to admob.  things can be easily changed. no need to worry about doing something "wrong" really.

Comment: @binnyb : There is an attribute called testing device id in the admob sdk. Why is that required? There is a warning in the admob documentation - "Warning: Make sure you're in test mode during development to avoid being disabled for clicking your own ads. See the Best Practices guide for more details on enabling test ads." How will admobknow that I am clicking my own add?

Comment: admob has all sorts of ways to determine what type of clicks may seem fraudulent(clicking your own real ads is not permitted).  use the provided device ID when observing LogCat while testing